# Почему БД не используют индекс с оператором !=?

Tags: sql

Т.е такой поиск считается неэффективным.
Однако, почему? Разве не достаточно при обходе дерева идти по дереву точно так же, как и с "=", но выбирая противоположный узел?

Comment: != подразумевает неизбежный обход всего дерева целиком, в то время как = позволяет пропускать большие куски дерева при первом же несовпадении

Comment: при поиске по бинарному дереву, решения в какую сторону идти дальше принимается в зависимости от того больше искомый элемент текущего узла или меньше. Если искать __все элементы неравные указанному `X`__ то и двигаться придется в обе стороны на каждом уровне. Т.е. пройти все дерево

Comment: Погуглите термин **sargable**. Не могу указать одну какую-то хорошую статью по теме, придётся пройтись по нескольким источникам.

Answer (score 2):

В каждом узле бинарного дерева будет осуществлён переход к следующему узлу путём сравнения значения текущего узла и значения в условии.

Например условие:

```
WHERE id != 50
```

И предположим, узлы выглядят так:

```
  50
 /  \  
30  70
```

В самом первом узле, 50!=30 и 50!=70, оба условия верны. Куда идти дальше?
БД этого не знает, поэтому индекс не будет использован.

Comment: Поведение с `<>` эквивалентно  `!=`?

Comment: @Sheridan Да, это одно и тоже. Оператор <> более старый.